# Monitor UDP packet in wireshark

Tags: network, wireshark, udp

I am trying to monitor udp packets from server to client in Wireshark at both end. Can I get any clue in Wireshark with which I find out that ok this specific udp packet is what I sent and received at the server side? in order to measure the latency of the udp packet from client to server. With TCP it is easy that I monitor the sequence number of the packets, but how to do it with UDP. any suggestions would be kind.

Comment: how do you create udp traffic?

Comment: Basically I am sending video streaming using webrtc, so RTP packets from the application layer contains the udp packet and I want to analyse the latency of layer 4 rather then layer 7.

Comment: Is there any sample of this traffic? what do you mean by monitor with sequence numbers?

Comment: With RTP there is the RTP sequence number - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#Packet_header.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes RTP have sequence number but so you mean with that sequence number the same udp packet will be there right? like RTP packet is encapsulated in the UDP packet so we can see the RTP sequence number to find out ok this is the same udp packet which I sent and recieved at the client side by using RTP sequence number?

Comment: Correct, the RTP sequence number is mostly unique for the same UDP association and thus you could match packets sniffed on various places in the traffic flow to each other.